# Devise strong params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, devise

I am trying to implement devise in one of my rails 4 projects and am getting a weird error.  When I run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

I get the following:

```
rake aborted!
NameError: undefined local variable or method `params' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-4.1.4/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
/home/zach/HandCoOp/project/HandCo-op/app/models/user.rb:8:in `<class:User>'
/home/zach/HandCoOp/project/HandCo-op/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `block in load_file'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:633:in `new_constants_in'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:442:in `load_file'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:480:in `load_missing_constant'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `const_get'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `block in constantize'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `each'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `inject'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `constantize'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:552:in `get'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:583:in `constantize'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise.rb:297:in `get'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:77:in `to'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `modules'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:89:in `routes'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:156:in `default_used_route'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/mapping.rb:66:in `initialize'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise.rb:331:in `new'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise.rb:331:in `add_mapping'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:221:in `block in devise_for'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:220:in `each'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:220:in `devise_for'
/home/zach/HandCoOp/project/HandCo-op/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:337:in `instance_exec'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:337:in `eval_block'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:315:in `draw'
/home/zach/HandCoOp/project/HandCo-op/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:71:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
/home/zach/HandCoOp/project/HandCo-op/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:379:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

this is my model and the error is pointing to "params.require" which according to strong params, it should be solid.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :confirmable and :activatable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  params.require(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Does anyone know what is going on? maybe I am missing a gem required for strong params? I just don't know.  I will keep looking into the issue and thank you anyone who knows my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look how to use strong params? Delete this `params.require(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)` line from model.

In your controller (assume `users_controller.rb`):

```
def create 
  @user = User.new(user_params)
end
```

And then at the bottom of a file:

```
 private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
```

Defined this in your controller, your create method will be working.

Comment: I did, I will re-read to make sure I understand but a more pressing error is now occuring and I think it has to do with my RVM active support gem.  I will post in a new post thanks for all your help Andrey!